# How do I prevent JAXB from generating Java from imported schema?

Tags: java, jaxb

I've got two Java projects, both generate Java classes based on a schema definition, I'm using xjc to create the classes.

My second project depends on a class from the first project, and in particular, one of the classes I'd like to generate in my second project needs to use one of the types from the first project.

To accomplish this dependency at the schema level, I'm using a simple `xsd:import` to map the namespace to a particular schema.

JAXB works just fine with this condition, except it also generates the first project's types in the second project.  So after running have something like this:

```
Project A
  +-- com.foo.bar
    +-- TypeA

Project B
  +-- com.foo.asdf
    +-- TypeB
  +-- com.foo.bar
    +-- TypeA
```

The second "TypeA" is undesirable, and I'd like to never generate it in the first place.  How do I instruct JAXB not to generate the classes for "TypeA" that it finds as a result of the import statement?

Comment: Can't you just let it generate the classes, and ignore the ones you don't need, or repackage the ones you do need?

Comment: @skaffman, I'm running the whole thing through ant and I'm currently running a task to delete the extra classes, but it seemed to me like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Customize it as a DOM element (`<jaxb:dom/>`).

```
<xs:element name="a" type="a:Type">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <jaxb:dom/>
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
```

You may be also interested in [separate/episodic schema compilation](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide#UserGuide-Separateschemacompilation).

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood...but I added this annotation to the element in ProjectB and recompiled, I still got ProjectA's types, I tried removing the import, and that generates an error.  Can you clarify your example a bit?

Comment: jaxb:dom only helps to remove the dependency from B to A. You will get a DOM Element instead of AType - so there is not compile-time dependency.

A more correct solution is with episodes. Check this Maven project example:

http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb2-plugin-sample-episode/

See also this blog entry from Kohsuke:

http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/09/05/separate-compilation-jaxb-ri-21

Comment: Thanks -- using episodes fixes my issue.

Answer (score 0):

another option is if you google episodic compiling so if project A already has jaxb objects, you can use it's episode file to compile project B's jaxb object but NOT have to recompile project A's xsds to objects.